# \mapsto equivalent to \rightrightarrows?

Tags: symbols, arrows, stacking-symbols

The command `\rightrightarrows` (of `amsfonts`) stacks two `\to`/`\rightarrow` vertically, is there an equivalent command that would stack two `\mapsto`? If not how would one define it to be consistent with the definition of `\rightrightarrows`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\mapstochar` does not really allow to stack the two characters as close as in the case of `\rightrightarrows`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for scalable \fontdimen8
\usepackage{amssymb} % for comparison with \rightrightarrow
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows} % for smaller arrow heads

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mapsmapsto}{\mathpalette\@mapsmapsto\relax}
\newcommand*{\@mapsmapsto}[2]{%
   \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr
            \noalign{\kern\dimen@}%
            $#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \rightrightarrows B \mapsmapsto C$

$\scriptstyle A \rightrightarrows B \mapsmapsto C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \rightrightarrows B \mapsmapsto C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments:

- The whole `\fontdimen` stuff assigns to `\dimen@` the thickness of a fraction rule. With the package `amsmath` this will scale according to the current math style.
- The package `-old-arrows` provides "old-style" arrow heads. Loaded with tje option `old` it does not replace the standard definitions but rather defines a `\var...` version of the existing arrows.

If you don't mind the two vertical strokes almost touching each other you can eliminate the whole `\fontdimen` stuff and the line containing `\noalign`

```
\newcommand*{\@mapsmapsto}[2]{%
    \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr
            $#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}
```

obtaining

[image]

Comment: I actually want the bar to be altogether, maybe we would have a better chance adding a bar at the right side of a ```\rightrightarrows``` to be more consistent with their vertical spacing? I could not find the definition of ```\rightrightarrows``` in the style files of ```amsfonts```.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot `\rightrightarrows` is no stacked symbol but rather a single glyph; you won't find any composite definition for it. If you want the vertical bar to be "joined" replace `\kern\dimen@` by `\kern-\dimen@` in the argument of `\noalign`.

Comment: That's right. Actually I just realized there is a difference between ```\rightrightarrows``` and ```\tto```, your solution extends ```\tto``` which I actually prefer.

Answer (score 2):

After all this is what I am using. Essentially I used campa's template to redefine `\tto` for coherence and defined a long version of both symbols.

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tto}{\mathpalette\@tto\relax}
\newcommand*{\@tto}[2]{%
   \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\varrightarrow$\cr
            \noalign{\kern-\dimen@}%
            $#1\varrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\longtto}{\mathpalette\@longtto\relax}
\newcommand*{\@longtto}[2]{%
   \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\varlongrightarrow$\cr
            \noalign{\kern-\dimen@}%
            $#1\varlongrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mapstto}{\mathpalette\@mapstto\relax}
\newcommand*{\@mapstto}[2]{%
   \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr
            \noalign{\kern-\dimen@}%
            $#1\mapstochar\varrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\longmapstto}{\mathpalette\@longmapstto\relax}
\newcommand*{\@longmapstto}[2]{%
   \dimen@\fontdimen8
       \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
       \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
       \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
   \mathrel{%
      \vcenter{%
         \vbox{%
            \baselineskip\z@skip
            \lineskip\z@
            \ialign{##\cr$#1\mapstochar\varlongrightarrow$\cr
            \noalign{\kern-\dimen@}%
            $#1\mapstochar\varlongrightarrow$\cr}%
         }%
      }%
   }%
}
```